# EOSIO Tutorial cleos create account Error 3080004

Tags: eos

I am doing the eos tutorial on [eos tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts-with-cleos) and I am getting an error when I attempt to create an account. I have followed the tutorial, and it has not yet covered setting cpu etc. Here is the command:

```
# cleos create account eosio fred13 EOS7Y2Ej...YtRrs7 EOS8XfHv..uDgB
Error 3080004: Transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stake some EOS for `net bandwidth` and `cpu bandwidth`.
Click [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1091/how-to-take-back-delegated-cpu-or-net-amounts) for more info.

Moreover, the account name should be of 12 characters long. Allowed characters are a-z and 1-5. No uppercase is allowed

Comment: I'd given up that line of exploring, now I am excited to give it another go. Thanks!